# Convert a callback Swift JSON AnyObject into a NSDictionary

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary, anyobject

I have a network connection with reads the data using JSON and gives a callback;

```
executeRequestURL(requestURL: url, taskCallback: {(status, resp) -> Void in

            if (status == true) {
                if let results = resp as? NSDictionary {
                    print ("\(results.count) results found")
                    let list = results.allValues.first as! NSArray

                    print (list)
                }

            } else {
                print ("Error -- \(resp)")
            }
        })
```

This calls;

```
private class func executeRequestURL(requestURL: NSURL, taskCallback: @escaping (Bool, AnyObject?) -> ()) {
        print ("Attempting URL -- \(requestURL)")

        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: kAPI_TIMEOUT)

        let session: URLSession = URLSession.shared


        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Data is empty")
                return
            }

            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            //print(json)

            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse , 200...299 ~= response.statusCode {
                taskCallback(true, json as AnyObject?)
            } else {
                taskCallback(false, json as AnyObject?)
            }

        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

The problem I have is that I want to read the results into a dictionary, loop through it and create objects.

For now, I will put my code in the executeRequestURL just to ensure it works, but I intend to seperate this code away for the required entity.

Question:

How do I read the `resp` as a dictionary?

Thanks

Sample response follows;

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "uid": "coll_20ce39424470457c925f823fc150b3d4",
      "title": "Popular",
      "temp_image": "",
      "body": "",
      "active": true,
      "slug": "popular",
      "created": "2014-10-25T12:45:54+00:00",
      "modified": "2014-10-25T12:45:54.159000+00:00",
      "ends_on": "2100-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what you got in the resp ? Show that

Comment: Its a really long JSON.  The reading of JSON is working fine.  I am unable to post the JSON data for security reasons.   But its returning as <anyobject>  This is fine, its abstracting away what the data is, but when I want to read it I want to convert it into a dictionary

Comment: well I asked for data so that I can provide you a model in which you may not need a dictionary, try to post some dummy response

Comment: added sample response (cut down).  All the responses to this specific call have the same structure.

Comment: There are approx 20 objects being returned.  I want to loop through the dictionary of results, creating the entity for each item within the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the JSON is a dictionary, return a dictionary (`[String:Any]`) from the callback. In Swift 3 `AnyObject` has become `Any`. The strong type system of Swift encourages to be always as specific as possible.

Do a better error handling! You should return an error rather than just `false`.

The code uses the new Swift 3 structs `URL` and `URLRequest`

```
private class func executeRequestURL(requestURL: URL, taskCallback: @escaping (Bool, [String:Any]?) -> ()) {
  print ("Attempting URL -- \(requestURL)")

  let request = URLRequest(url: requestURL, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: kAPI_TIMEOUT)

  let session = URLSession.shared


  let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in

    guard error == nil else {
      print(error)
      taskCallback(false, nil)
      return
    }
    guard let data = data else {
      print("Data is empty")  // <- this will never be reached. If there is no error,
      taskCallback(false, nil) // data is always non-nil.
      return
    }
    if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse , 200...299 ~= response.statusCode {
      let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as!  [String:Any]
      taskCallback(true, json)
    } else {
      taskCallback(false, nil)
    }
  })
  task.resume()
}
```

The JSON result contains a dictionary with one key `objects` which contains an array of dictionaries. JSON collection types are very easy to distinguish: `{}` is dictionary, `[]` is array.

---

To map the JSON to objects create a struct

```
struct Item {

  var uid : String
  var title : String
  var tempImage : String
  var body : String
  var active : Bool
  var slug : String
  var created : String
  var modified : String
  var endOn : String
}
```

and an array

```
var items = [Item]()
```

Then map the dictionaries to `Item`

```
if let objects = json["objects"] as? [[String:Any]] {
  for object in objects {
    let uid = object["uid"] as! String
    var title = object["title"] as! String
    var tempImage = object["temp_image"] as! String
    var body = object["body"] as! String
    var active = object["active"] as! Bool
    var slug = object["slug"] as! String
    var created = object["created"] as! String
    var modified  = object["modified"] as! String
    var endOn  = object["end_on"] as! String
    let item = Item(uid: uid, title: title, tempImage:tempImage, body: body, active: active, slug: slug, created: created, modified: modified, endOn: endOn)
    items.append(item)

  }
```

The JSON values seem to come from a database which includes always all fields so the forced unwrapped values are safe.

Comment: `Do a better error handling! You should return an error rather than just false.` --- I'm just getting the reading to work first, it will handle the error better, but right now I'm working on the reading

Comment: Thanks for the assistance on the callback; the dictionary does return fine -- the issue is looping through the dictionary, and grabbing the array which is the first record; which is an array of records.

Comment: I added a suggestion to map the dictionaries to a custom struct. A third party library is not needed.

Comment: Accepted your answer. Many thanks, this is most helpful

Answer (score 1):

I've done it like so:

```
func getHttpData(urlAddress : String)
    {
        // Asynchronous Http call to your api url, using NSURLSession:
        guard let url = URL(string: urlAddress) else
        {
            print("Url conversion issue.")
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            // Check if data was received successfully
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                do {
                    // Convert NSData to Dictionary where keys are of type String, and values are of any type
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]
                    // Call whatever function you want to do with your dictionary
                    useMyDictionary(dictionary: json)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    // Something went wrong
                }
            }
            else if error != nil
            {
                print(error)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

Comment: I've adapted my local code (not the query code) to use the callback to send back the dictionary, but I'm still struggling on how to actually loop through the dictionary as the dictionary contains child dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

There are many other ways but I like to do it using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper). it looks cleaner to me. So just create a new Swift file, import `ObjectMapper` and write below code.

```
 class yourDataModel: Mappable {

// MARK: - Constants & Variables

var myObjects: [yourDataModel]

required init?(_ map: Map) {
    myObjects = []

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    myObjects               <- map["objects"]
}

}

class YourCustomObjects: Mappable {

// MARK: - Constants & Variables

var userId:String
var title:String
var tempimage:String
var body:String
var active:Bool
var slug : String
var createdDate:String
var modifiedDate:String
var endDate:String

// MARK: - init

required init?(_ map: Map) {

    userId = ""
    title = ""
    tempimage = ""
    body = ""
    active = false
    slug = ""
    createdDate = ""
    modifiedDate = ""
    endDate = ""

}

func mapping(map: Map) {

    userId                      <- map["uid"]
    title                       <- map["title"]
    tempimage                   <- map["temp_image"]
    body                        <- map["body"]
    active                      <- map["active"]
    slug                        <- map["slug"]
    createdDate                 <- map["created"]
    modifiedDate                <- map["modified"]
    endDate                     <- map["ends_on"]

}

}
```

Basically its your model class, now you just have to pass it your result in JSON which will be an AnyObject hopefully, and it will give you an array containing all your "objects" in it. You can use it like below

```
if let data = Mapper<yourDataModel>().map(resp){
    print(data)
 }
```

Try this, and let me know if you face any difficulty.

Comment: Never heard of maps before. I will give it a go; looks interesting

Comment: its JSON mapping basically.